# How to test infinite loop Horizontal pager content in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-testing

I am trying to write UI test cases to validate screen content.

Composable screen has below content

- Text
- Button
- Infinite Loop Horizontal pager to display texts

I am getting below error when i try with below test case

```
    @Test
fun testMyScreen() {
    composeRule.setContent {
        MyScreen()
    }
    composeRule.onNodeWithText("Name").assertExists()
}

androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.android.ComposeNotIdleException: Idling resource timed out: possibly due to compose being busy.
```